High level component unmounting on route change
I'm trying to add a websocket to my website for real time notifications and messaging. I figured the Navbar was a solid place to put it as a user always has the Navbar mounted.. Well, unfortunately I'm noticing that the Navbar consistently mounts and unmounts on route change. I figured it's because I don't have nested routes or anything like that because I was kinda lazy when I set it up, and it just seemed easier at the time. Fine! Annoyed I was like.. let's make the ultimate high level component by creating a new file WebSocketContext.jsx and import it into main, Then, the routerProvider will be a child of the WebSocketProvider, SURELY this will work. No. I am stumped why my websocket component keeps unmounting, Please help!
WebSocketContext.jsx:


import React, { createContext, useContext, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const WebSocketContext = createContext();

export const WebSocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const socketRef = useRef(null);
  const websocketServer = import.meta.env.VITE_API_WSS_URL + '/notifications'

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!socketRef.current) {
      socketRef.current = io(websocketServer, { transports : ['websocket'] });
      console.log('WebSocket connected');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <WebSocketContext.Provider value={socketRef.current}>
      {children}
    </WebSocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useWebSocket = () => useContext(WebSocketContext);



Main.jsx:


import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { WebSocketProvider } from './WebSocketContext';

//component imports


const router = createBrowserRouter([
//buncha routes!
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <WebSocketProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </WebSocketProvider>
)



I used to have React Strict Mode on here, but I took it off thinking it might be the problem. Didn't help. I've also console logged the useEffect and it is indeed going off everytime. I don't know if this matters, but I'm also using "location.href = newRoute" for reroutes.. This is quite annoying any insight would be helpful, thanks!

The issue you are facing is likely related to using location.href which triggers a fresh page load and causes your app to completely rerender. I would suggest using the <Link> and <NavLink> components of react-router-dom for navigating within your application.

This worked! I had no idea that would be the problem, thanks!
